# Can I use glib in WP8, WP8.1 or W10M?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, autotools, glib, windows-10-mobile

How can I use glib in Windows Phone 8 / 8.1 or Windows 10 Mobile C / C++ application? Is it possible?

Should I somehow try to use autotools or should I create Visual Studio project and add all the files needed?

Comment: GLib already maintains VS project files, that said I imagine it won't work on winphone or has even been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store apps rely on Windows Runtime and run in sandboxed environment. GLib provides the core application building blocks for libraries and applications written in C. It provides the core object system used in GNOME, the main loop implementation, and a large set of utility functions for strings and common data structures. For Winows Store apps, there are some limitations or restrictionsin security, inter-app communication, low-level system functionality, usable APIs, etc.. If you wanna port your app based on Glib to Windows Store app, you'd better leverage the power of Windows Runtime and other high-quality third party libraries specific to Windows Store.